# Exported PNG is heavy sized than generated by Save For Web

Tags: photoshop-scripting

I've made a script which is being used in HTML panel for saving files as PNG or JPG based on selected option! below is my code.

```
function saveMain() {

                var finalName = userName.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase();

                if (ext === ".png") {
                    var saveFile = new File(filePathFolder + "/" + finalName + ext);

                    pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();

                    pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;

                    app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
                } else {
                    var saveFile = new File(filePathFolder + "/" + finalName + ext);

                    var saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
                    saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
                    saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
                    saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
                    saveOptions.quality = 10;

                    app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
                }

            }
```

The Problem is my exported PNG side is way too big eg. 5.88 MB and the same file generated from save for web is only 38 KB! what am I missing in configuration! Thanks!

[image]

Edit : Problem is fixed by using ExportOptionsSaveForWeb instead of saveAs. but as Billy kerr pointed out even saving manually as Save As doesn't output such a big file so what is going on! use below code which trigerring sized PNG!

```
var saveFile = new File("~/Desktop/test.png");
pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

Comment: Did you rescale the image when using save for web?  Check the dimensions of these images. Also, are they both the same type of PNG. i.e. PNG8 or PNG24?.

Comment: You are not doing a web png. You are doing the same thig as saving from the normal save dialog which is a png meant for print. Full size, full color and with all metadata embedded.

Comment: Well i didn't rescaled but @joojaa seems right. so how am I supposed to export as save for web .  seems should use ExportOptionsSaveForWeb instead of PNGSaveOptions!

Comment: @joojaa can you add your comment as answer so that i can accept it!

Comment: @DesignPhoenix - perhaps convert it to Indexed colour mode (i.e. PNG8), before you save the PNG. Also I really suspect there has been some scaling too. You need to check if the PNGs are the same dimensions and type of PNG. Open them up in PS, and compare the image sizes, and the colour modes. If you see any differences there, then that explains the huge file size differences.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks but as I already mentioned the reason was I use saveAs instead of ExportOptionsSaveForWeb . and for your knowledge both PNG size are same and about color mode are same too. Issue is fixed just can't accept since it is as comment :D :D

Comment: @DesignPhoenix - I don't think this explains the massive difference in file sizes you are experiencing. I just tested using Save As, and compared it with Save for Web. The result was two identical images, and the file sizes are almost the same. [See example here](https://imgur.com/k2Tedle). Something else must be going on.

Comment: @BillyKerr OMG it's true! I also followed same. from save as the size is 372 KB ; and save for web is 343 KB!!! did you tried using my function? what size are you getting!

Comment: No, sorry I didn't use your script.  Just File > Save As.  I am not familiar with scripting at all (wish I was though!).  It's almost as if your script is saving the PSD, and not a PNG.  I wish I could help you solve it.  Joojaa is more of an expert in this regard. Hopefully he'll chip in soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96750/discussion-between-design-phoenix-and-billy-kerr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get Photoshop to save an adequately compressed PNG from a script.  Using the ScriptingListener plugin.  I just copied and pasted the code from the ScriptingListener.log. Obviously the save path is for my Desktop, but I'm sure you'll be able to fix that.

```
var idsave = charIDToTypeID( "save" );
    var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
        var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idMthd = charIDToTypeID( "Mthd" );
        var idPNGMethod = stringIDToTypeID( "PNGMethod" );
        var idquick = stringIDToTypeID( "quick" );
        desc9.putEnumerated( idMthd, idPNGMethod, idquick );
        var idPGIT = charIDToTypeID( "PGIT" );
        var idPGIT = charIDToTypeID( "PGIT" );
        var idPGIN = charIDToTypeID( "PGIN" );
        desc9.putEnumerated( idPGIT, idPGIT, idPGIN );
        var idPNGf = charIDToTypeID( "PNGf" );
        var idPNGf = charIDToTypeID( "PNGf" );
        var idPGAd = charIDToTypeID( "PGAd" );
        desc9.putEnumerated( idPNGf, idPNGf, idPGAd );
        var idCmpr = charIDToTypeID( "Cmpr" );
        desc9.putInteger( idCmpr, 6 );
    var idPNGF = charIDToTypeID( "PNGF" );
    desc8.putObject( idAs, idPNGF, desc9 );
    var idIn = charIDToTypeID( "In  " );
    desc8.putPath( idIn, new File( "C:\\Users\\Billy\\Desktop\\testimage.png" ) );
    var idDocI = charIDToTypeID( "DocI" );
    desc8.putInteger( idDocI, 195 );
    var idCpy = charIDToTypeID( "Cpy " );
    desc8.putBoolean( idCpy, true );
    var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStage" );
    var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStageType" );
    var idsaveBegin = stringIDToTypeID( "saveBegin" );
    desc8.putEnumerated( idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveBegin );
executeAction( idsave, desc8, DialogModes.NO );
```

testimage.png is the output file

My comparison here shows the output file size compared to Save As from within Photoshop GUI, and Save for Web (Legacy)

[image]

Comment: By the way, this is the first time I have ever tried anything like this. Perhaps I ought to look into this scripting lark.  So anyway, big LOL's if I got anything wrong.  That does look like a hell of a lot of code!!!

Comment: Yeah.  Scriptlistener plugin is best start.btw you can you adobe extendscript toolkit to directly run your script without saving it or you can use vs code plugin too!  And well this is same as we do it manually so for sure it won't have that big size issue and welcome to scripting world lol!  Btw as of that adobe forum "PngMethod" is one which is related for compression!  Btw +1 for your try and please don't leave scripting world And instead of that long desktop path u can use "˜/Desktop" Because username varies as per pc

Comment: Fyi, if you install SuperpPNG plugin, (http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/) you'll be able to save quantized pngs with scripting: optimized pngs with 8bit alpha (similar to what tinypng.com does)

Comment: yeah i used it once! it uses PNG-Quant technology to compress pixel data :D it saves upto 70% size :D but tinyPNG is one step ahead of PNG-Quant; i just couldn't found solution like tinyPNG xD

Answer (score 2):

**It's because my function just FORCED photoshop to export PNG without compression**

So after a long of discussion, chatting and research (Thanks @Billy Kerr; you can see our chat from comment section) we finally figured out what the ***CAUSE*** is!

so basically in all type of export or save as photoshop uses some sort of algorithms and it converts/optimizes as per users input but somehow by my code (obviously it's script of photoshop so no wonder) photoshop was exporting all PNG as the flattened version of my document in printing PNG of Adobe Photoshop's format so it was maximum possible quality of my image that's why image size was going too heavy as much as 8 MB while save for web was exporting the image with same quality around 300 KB size :)

**TLDR:** Photoshop got dark secrets lol and it's always amusing to mess with one of them so the solution was instead of saving it as Photoshop's PNG I had to go with SaveForWeb Options and thanks @joojaa for suggesting that! all credits of solution goes to joojaa! Cheers :)

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with this "bug".  https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2573336

Comment: Yeah maybe because i didn't specified Compression Ratio!  Will dig im tomorrow since already out of office :P

Comment: I've  now added an answer that seems to fix your problem. Take a look.

Comment: Looked already :D